# Python linear interpolation between rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, rows

I have a dataframe

`data=pd.DataFrame({'data1':[10,20,30], 'data2':[15,25,35], 'data3':[20,30,40], 'data3':[25,35,35]})`

I wanted to interpolate between the rows, depending on my input n.
here n=2

so my new_data must constain  n*len(data)

As I tried  np.linspace but I am getting new length as n*len(data)-1

expected to get

{
data1  data2  data3
10.0   15.0   25.0
15.0   20.0   30.0
20.0   25.0   35.0
25.0   30.0   35.0
30.0   35.0   35.0                                                                                                                   20.0   25.0   30.0}

I thought of taking the last row as the interpolation between the last and first row from the input data set

Comment: Can you add an example what you expect to get? If you interpolate [10, 20, 30] you will get 5 points, not 6.

Comment: data1  data2  data3
10.0   15.0   25.0
15.0   20.0   30.0
20.0   25.0   35.0
25.0   30.0   35.0
30.0   35.0   35.0                                                                                                                   20.0   25.0    30.0.   I thought of taking the last row as the interpolation between tha last and first row from the input data set

Answer (score 0):

Using np.interp() to do the interpolation:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'data1': [10, 20, 30],
    'data2': [15, 25, 35],
    'data3': [20, 30, 40],
    'data4': [25, 35, 35]})
n = 2

df = data.append(data.iloc[0]).reset_index(drop=True)  # add first column for interpolation only

x = np.linspace(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), (len(df) - 1) * n + 1)  # x axis values to calculate

result = df.apply(lambda c: np.interp(x, df.index, c), axis=0).iloc[:-1]  # drop last column
```

Comment: @Unni Yes, it already does that. You add first row to the end so interpolation can be done, then remove it at the end. The last line is then interpolated between original last and original first.